# Standard for application-specific template directories in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings

I guess this is a question related to best practises in Django development.
I'm trying to  build a web service with a main page (`base.html`) that contains multiple apps. I would like to make the apps self-contained, so I've made a `templates` directory in each app, and would also like to take advantage of the template inheritance feature of Django to make this whole thing as fluid as possible.

Now my concern is, where should I put the `base.html` in my project, so that the system knew where to find it?
Also, what changes should I make in the `settings.py` file in order for the system to be able to connect the templates? Is there a standard or a known method that takes minimal effort for this sort of arrangement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common design pattern that I have both seen and used is to have a centralized "app" as a part of your project that contains all the shared "stuff" you care to use in other applications. So you might have the following directory structure:

```
base/
  static/
    css/
      common.css
    js/
      common.js
  templates/
    base.html
myapp1/
  urls.py
  views.py
  templates/
  ...
myapp2/
  urls.py
  views.py
  templates/
  ...
myproject/
  settings.py
  urls.py
```

Now you just include the "base" application just like any other, and you put shared stuff inside it. Other applications can refer to templates that live there, and can include any common libraries that you may want to share.

In settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['base', 'myapp1', 'myapp2']
```

Comment: Would or should this `base/` be the same folder as the one containing the `settings.py` file?

Comment: When I've used this pattern, I have had my settings.py in another folder (typically a "project" level folder). So, imagine another folder at the same level as `myapp1` or `myapp2` that has the same name as the project itself. Inside there is the settings.py file, as well as the project-level URLs (urls.py), the latter of which could include application-specific URLs.

Comment: This is discouraged in Django documentation. According to the documentation, Django explains that each app should be self-contained as much as possible do a specific job for the user. In that case, all apps are dependent on the base app in this method where base app literally serves nothing to the user.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the `templates` folder in the project folder (ie folder contains `settings.py`).

as @danialroseman said, you just need to update the `DIRS` in `TEMPLATES` variable in `settings.py`. Let the project folder be `myproject`(ie folder  contains `settings.py`)::

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',

        ### ADD YOUR DIRECTORY HERE LIKE SO:
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'myproject', 'templates')],
        ...
```

you dont need to create a seperate app.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a central app for this. The TEMPLATES setting also includes an option for DIRS, which is a list of directories that will always be searched. So you can set this to an appropriate directory - eg `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` and put your non-app-specific templates such as base.html there.